# How to fix out of memory error in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, memory

I use this code to basically read around 800 .TIF files into a multi-dimensional array. Each tif file is 3500x7500.

```
%Automate the precip ingestion process
precipFile = which('PRECIPRATE.20110615.000000.tif'); %Location details of the files using example data
precipFileList = dir([fileparts(precipFile) filesep '*.tif']); %List of all precip files
precipFileNames = {precipFileList.name}'; %Names of all precip files

%Create a multidimensional array to store the precipitation
precip = zeros(3500,7000,length(precipFileNames)); %Pre-allocating an array

for k = 1:length(precipFileNames)
    precip(:,:,k) = imread(precipFileNames{k}); %Read all precip file    
end
```

But this is giving me

```
"Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options."
```

The code works fine if I try for a dozen files.

So, how can I fix this? I might have to even deal with 2000-3000 files eventually.

Comment: A 3500 x 7000 x 12 double matrix will occupy ~2.4GB of RAM so you are bound to genuinely run out of memory. Why do you want to load so many files at once and keep them all in memory ? It may be better to just load it one by one and work with the images.

Comment: What does `memory` return? The function is mentioned in the error message for a good reason!

Comment: Also, my guess is `imread` returns you `uint8` so it may be useful to preallocate array of the same type. `zeros` will give you a double array.

Comment: @RandomGuy Thanks. I need to do mathematical operations on all the files together (say sum, mean, multiple etc.). How can I do it without keeping all the files in memory? Also, imread for one file gives me a 3500x7500 single.

Comment: @maximusdooku you can set up a temporary variable of size `3500 x 7000`, and use cumulative quantities. Like adding each new image to this, and dividing by `n` in the end to get an average.

Comment: Just to set the records straight: you can't *fix* out-of-memory errors, because they are related to the amount of memory a) you have installed on your machine, b) required by your code. You can just *avoid* such errors, not *fix* them.

Comment: @Alessiox unless OP mistakenly wrote `zeros(n)` instead of `zeros(n,1)` :) But it seems their memory need is genuine in this case...

Comment: There are thing which can be done to avoid the errors like, downsample images after reading and before storing, process images one at the time and discard when used, ... There is also way to work with [big data](http://se.mathworks.com/discovery/big-data-matlab.html) in Matlab. However solutions to this kind of problems may be different depending on what the user needs and the needs are not described here.